# Pulling force between two physics bodies connected by a joint

Tags: swift, scenekit, game-physics

**What I am trying to do:**

I created two `SCNNode`s and corresponding `SCNPhysicsBody`s (both dynamic and affected by gravity) and I wanted to connect them using a `SCNPhysicsHingeJoint`. Just to test things out `node1` has an additional joint in order to be pinned into the scene and not fall down due to gravity. The nodes are connected to one another by `joint`. So when I start the scene `node1` is just pinned into the scene and `node2` is hanging downwards. Now *I want to ascertain the force pulling on the joint* which should be equals -9.8 (assuming no swinging) because the [gravitational acceleration is equals -9.8](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsworld/1512855-gravity) (default value for `gravity` property) and the default mass is equals 1 whereof the force pulling on the joint should make -9.8. I do not want to calculate that force pulling though because my scene is meant to get considerably more complicated. **Therefore I was wondering whether there is a property or method for figuring out the pulling force between two nodes and there physics bodies connected by a joint?**

```
let node1 = SCNNode(geometry: SCNCylinder(radius: 0.125, height: 2))
node1.position.x = -1.625
node1.rotation = SCNVector4(1, 0, 0, Float.pi/2)
node1.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: node1.geometry!, options: nil))
node1.physicsBody!.isAffectedByGravity = true
node1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 1
node1.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 1
node1.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 1
rootNode.addChildNode(node1)

let node2 = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 3, height: 0.25, length: 2, chamferRadius: 0))
node2.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: node2.geometry!, options: nil))
node2.physicsBody!.isAffectedByGravity = true
node2.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 1
node2.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 1
node2.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 1
rootNode.addChildNode(node2)

let irrelevantJoint = SCNPhysicsHingeJoint(body: node1.physicsBody!, axis: SCNVector3(0, 1, 0), anchor: SCNVector3(0, 0, -0.125))
physicsWorld.addBehavior(irrelevantJoint)

let joint = SCNPhysicsHingeJoint(bodyA: node1.physicsBody!, axisA: SCNVector3(0, 1, 0), anchorA: SCNVector3(0, 0, 0.125),
                                 bodyB: node2.physicsBody!, axisB: SCNVector3(0, 0, 1), anchorB: SCNVector3(-1.5, 0, 0))
physicsWorld.addBehavior(joint)
```

**What I tried:**

I was hoping I could use the `SCNPhysicsContactDelegate` and the `physicsWorld(_:didEnd:)` to get the force (or impulse) on `joint`. Whenever the method is called a `SCNPhysicsContact` is being created which lets you access its `collisionImpulse` property, so I was hoping for a negative impulse which was not the case. I just got and `collisionImpulse` of 0. *Any ideas on how to get the pulling force between two physics bodies connected by a joint?*

Comment: Are you sure you selected the right instrument? _*SCNPhysicsHingeJoint*
A physics behavior that connects two bodies and allows them to pivot around each other on a single axis._ Thus there can't be collision between such two bodies, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I think it is. I want two nodes (and their physics bodies) to be connected to one another and `node2` is supposed to swing around `node1`. *And additionally I want to ascertain the force pulling on that pivot or `node1`*

Answer (score 1):

Game physics simulation does not require force calculation in the simple joints. Those are geometrical constraints and convergence is achieved by solver iterations. Force calculation is an additional expense that costs computational time and in a comprehensive solver would be enabled explicitly and disabled by default. Not all solvers have that and looking at the `SCNPhysicsWorld` I don't see any signs of it, so I am pretty sure it is not implemented.

On a positive note, I believe that the calculation of the forces applied to each body in your scene is quite simple. You just have to update the current frame and previous frame velocities of the body each frame and calculate acceleration as their difference divided by the timestamp. Multiply it by the body mass and this will give you the force. In the same way, you can calculate the angular velocity and torque, based on the inertia of the body.

If you do need the force and torque in the joint this isn't as simple so the only thing I can suggest is to describe how you were planning to use it to see if there is an alternative solution to achieve this final goal.

Comment: well the problem is the nodes are not moving and I just want to calculate the **stress** on the joints... (therefore no change in velocities)

Comment: I'm afraid there is no work around, you'll have to calculate static reaction forces either yourself (https://www.engineer4free.com/4/how-to-solve-3d-statics-problems and https://www.engineer4free.com/statics.html) or use a solver that does this calculation for you

Comment: how would you calculate the force on for example a bridge which is not moving... when f.e. a car drives over it

Comment: Short answer - as described in the video I posted. Long answer, depends on precision. In the most simplified case (zero vehicle acceleration and reaction force is calculated based on a single point of contact F=Mg, rather than 4 wheels and the bridge assumed to be 2 hinge joints with reactions F1 and F2), you have 2 equations F1+F2=F and F1*L1=F2*L2 where L1 and L2 are distance from the bridge ends to the vehicle on the current frame. If a bridge is not flat, you'll have to do vector math in 2D, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As isp-zax described you can use delta v decided by the time passed and thus ascertain the acceleration.

```
var node1: SCNNode!
var timestamp: TimeInterval = 0
var lastVelocity: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3()
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    let dt = time - timestamp
    timestamp = time

    let velocity = node1.physicsBody!.velocity
    let dv = velocity.y - lastVelocity.y
    let a = Double(dv) / dt
    lastVelocity = velocity

    print("vertical acceleration: \(a) and vertical force: \(node1.physicsBody!.mass * a)")
}
```

You have to assign the `delegate` property of the `SCNView` to the handler which implements the method above. Additionally you need the handler to conform to the `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` protocol. The code above just computes the vertical acceleration but you can do the same in y and z direction.